# Can I use a DVI-D cable for a DVI-I graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, vga, dvi

I have a GTX N560 Ti Twin Frozr III MSI's Hawk Edition graphics card and it comes with 2 DVI-I Female ports and 1 Mini HDMI Female port.  Now I have a [DVI-D Male Cable](http://img.misco.eu/Resources/images/Modules/InformationBlocks/1210/CTG/CTG-1/154397-CablesToGo-DVI-D-2m-Dual-Link-Video-Cable-small.jpg) (both sides) and a [DVI-I Female to VGA Male converter](http://i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/dce07b8c-4697/k2-_1f8a58e8-632c-43df-8138-9bae092072db.v1.jpg) for my VGA monitor.

My question is that can I use my DVI-D cable for my DVI-I graphics card ?

Comment: You can certainly connect a DVI-D cable to a DVI-I port. The thing is, what kind of port on the monitor you will connect it to? If you want DVI-I (card) -> DVI-D cable -> DVI-I to VGA adapter -> VGA (monitor), then certainly it will NOT work.

Comment: @TomYan , you are right, that is my arrangement style and I am changing it to just DVI-I(card) -> DVI-I to VGA adapter - VGA cable, which will be better

Comment: It's not really "better", but "necessary".

Comment: @TomYan , :P my bad, yeah its necessary

Comment: Btw: http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-DVIVGAMM10-10-Feet-Display-Monitor/dp/B0024G48MO/

Comment: @TomYan, are you sure this will work? cause I was thinking this will work as it has worked before(when I rented it from a friend for graphics card testing) [http://www.flipkart.com/iconnect-world-dvi-i-male-24-5-pin-standard-vga-female-adapter-video-patch-cable/p/itmeddqhknvkm4uy?pid=ACCEDDQHN6RHRMQJ&ref=L%3A1430770869209023355&srno=p_7&query=DVI+to+vga&otracker=from-search]

Comment: As long as the DVI side of the adapter/cable has all the pins of DVI-A: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/DVI_Connector_Types-r.svg/277px-DVI_Connector_Types-r.svg.png that's why you can't involve a DVI-D cable

Comment: @TomYan , well I just read [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-1961578/dvi-dual-single-link.html) that dual link is better than single link for higher FPS and yeah I can't use a DVI-D cable for DVI-I because the additional 4 pins in DVI-I has to do something with RGB signals

Comment: The `link` thing only applies to the digital signal. So "single-link DVI-I" to VGA is the same as "dual-link DVI-I" to VGA, because the pins are bogus/unused.

Comment: @TomYan ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh so I am going to buy this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DVI-I cable have 4 additional wires to transport analog RGB signal. So, if your cable is DVI-D only your DVI to VGA converter will not work.

I assume that converter is a passive one.